# Link which also scrolls down to a specific element on another page

Tags: jquery, html

How i can create a link which target to a specific height of another page? For example, a link which targets to the last article (spesific div) of another page?

Comment: That's just good old steam-age hyperlinking with a #hash part at the right hand end of the url, which will link to a correspondingly named anchor in the hyperlinked document, eg. `mypath/mydoc.html#section1`, will link to `<a name="section1">Section 1</a>`. No need for javascript or jQuery.

Comment: Unless, @Beetroot, there *is* no named anchor on the target page. Then scrolling is more complicated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is very simple, you can just add `#elementId` to the link and `<html-element id="elementId" />` will be selected

if you dont have an element id, this is a workaround:

```
document.ready(function() { 
   if (document.URL.indexOf("scrollto=myTarget") !== -1) {
       $(".element element-textarea").attr("id","myTarget");
       window.location.href = "#myTarget";
   }
}
```

now you can call `http://www.asdf.com/myPage.whatever?scrollto=myTarget`. javascript will find the string "scrollto=myTarget" (not a real url-parameter!) and therefore scroll down.

Comment: and if its a class? `href="website.com/blabla#.elementclass"` ?

Comment: won't work afaik, cannot work imho since classes are not identities (so many html-elements will have same class, which one do you want to scroll to?)

Comment: i want to scroll down to 1 of this elements: `<div class="element element-textarea">
<h3>Photos</h3>
<p> </p>
<div class="wk-gallery wk-gallery-wall clearfix round margin ">`

Comment: try something like `$(".element element-textarea").attr("id","myTarget"); window.location.href = "#myTarget";` in the onload or document ready

Comment: thanks a lot efkah i think that window.location did the trick! YUPI!

Comment: Seems that with this window.location every view of those pages have been scrolled down to this element. I tried this in my head.php:`if (window.location.pathname == '/events*#gallery') { window.location.href = "#gallery"}` but its working only on chrome and not on firefox! Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: can you check my last comment please?

Comment: things are getting complicated over there. i'll edit my answer, but it get a bit... "hacky", i personally dont like the code anymore;-)

Comment: dirty but it works great! Thanks a lot for your effort and for your time! peace